# Trying a Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

For a college course, I have to produce a coding project over the course of 1 year. My current idea is a neural network that detects an image, processes what that image is, then reads it aloud in 2 different languages. My idea is to make this a website or a mobile app, and to use Python. Is this too ambitious? Or not ambitious enough? Or should I look at something completely different?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect question for the professor who knows about the intended scope and grading of that course

Comment: Sounds like a good project. for the backend side I would suggest a Flask app running a pre-trained classification network (PyTorch is my flavor). good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches for your project. I‘ve listed some of them here.

For your website/app itself:

- Either use a Python Library like Flask, Django or web for the backend part.
- Even though plain HTML/CSS/JS would be enough for your frontend part of the project, you might use jQuery for simplifying the upload process of an image.

Image Classification:

- To classify an image, you can either use a library like Tensorflow or PyTorch or just use an API like imagga (saving you a lot of work).
- Now, turning the result to speech can be made possible by using Google‘s Text-To-Speech library „gtts“.

I hope I could help you,
wish you luck for the project !

Comment: This is a big help, Thank you!